# Render an array in a view in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, render, kaminari

At the controller end, I have an array

> `@bookmarks = Bookmark.where('user_id = ? && note is NULL',current_user.id).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page_2]).per(4)`

Then at the View I have this render tag through which I want to render @bookmarks

> `<%= render @bookmarks %>`

Then there is page for _bookmark which will display @bookmarks

```
bookmark.title 
bookmark.created_at
```

But this process is giving me error of no partial. (I try to implement kaminari via Ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the render method like that will 'cause it to look for a partial in bookmarks/_bookmark.

you can also specify the partial and collection with `render partial: 'folder/mypartial', collection: @bookmarks`